# zend framework 2 (zfcadmin) and routing

Tags: zend-framework2

I want to create admin panel using ZfcAdmin module. I want to create routing, to manage users. Here is it:

```
<?php
    return array(
        'controllers' => array(
            'invokables' => array(
                'AdminUser\Controller\AdminUser' => 'AdminUser\Controller\AdminUserController',
            ),
        ),
        'view_manager' => array(
            'template_path_stack' => array(
                'admin-user' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
            ),
        ),

        'router' => array(
            'routes' => array(
                'zfcadmin' => array(
                    'may_terminate' => true,
                    'child_routes' => array(
                        'user' => array(
                            'type' => 'segment',
                            'options' => array(
                                'route' => '/user',
                                'defaults' => array(
                                    'controller' => 'AdminUser\Controller\AdminUser',
                                    'action'     => 'index',
                                ),
                            ),
                            'may_terminate' => true,
                            'child_routes' =>array(
                                'edit' => array(
                                    'type' => 'segment',
                                    'options' => array(
                                        'route' => '/edit/:user_id',
                                        'defaults' => array(
                                            'controller' => 'AdminUser\Controller\AdminUser',
                                            'action'     => 'edit',
                                        ),
                                    ),
                                ),
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    );
```

I request: `/admin/user` and it's ok, but when I want to receive URL like: `/admin/user/edit/1` I always get `/admin/user` I create the link this way:

`<?php $this->url('zfcadmin/user/edit', array(
                    'action'  => 'edit',
                    'user_id' => $user['user_id'],
                )) ?>`

why? what's wrong?

Comment: The route name you've assigned should be correct. Have you tried skipping the `action` argument outside of the parameters? `$this->url('..', array('user_id'=>$id))` since action is no parameter but rather a value of your configuration already. That's currently the only error i see. Furthermore: Since `:user_id` is a value, you should add `constraints` to only accept numeric values as user_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument in the [ZF2 Url view helper](https://packages.zendframework.com/docs/latest/manual/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.html#url-helper) is a `$name`.  Have you tried using `'edit'` like you've specified in your config?

I also think you may need to `echo` the value.

```
<?php echo $this->url('edit', array('action' => 'edit', 'user_id' => $user['user_id'],)); ?>
```

Comment: yes, I have and I receive error with message `Route with name "edit" not found`